# How to remove splash screen from my acer aspire laptop running ubuntu 16.10

Tags: boot, 16.10, bios, aspire-one

I have a Acer laptop running ubuntu 16.10 . I got this laptop from government for my good marks but every time I boot my laptop I have to see a creepy image of our chief minister after this image ubuntu logo appears. I want to remove this chief minister"s photo (splash screen). When I got this laptop it was running win 10 with same boot picture. Later I moved to ubuntu but the boot image is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Press F2 when you see the chief minister's face, you should be taken to a screen labelled "Setup utility" or similar, there should be a boot tab, under the boot tab there should be an option labelled "show boot logo" or similar
press enter and highlight disabled and your problem should be fixed. The boot logo option may not be under the boot tab. In that case you will need to look in all the tabs for such and option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . But there is no option in bios (boot).

Comment: @GauravThakur If so I'm afraid you'll ave to get used to your chief minister's face, or obtain a new computer. FYI, this has nothingto do with Ubuntu.